# Unity: Inspector can't find field of ScriptableObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble showing a public field of a ScriptableObject which is a child of the component I'm inspecting. While I can easily do this in another way, I need this method to work for other variables. (ReorderableLists)

I simplified the problem, maybe I was just doing something obvious wrong, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Code + error:
http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/temp/70243-error.png

```
class SomeComponent : MonoBehaviour{
   public MyScriptable scriptable; //instantiated and saved as asset
}

[Serializable] class MyScriptable : ScriptableObject{
   [SerializeField] public float value = 0.1f;
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(SomeComponent))] class SomeComponentEditor : Editor{
     public override void OnInspectorGUI() {

         if((target as SomeComponent).scriptable==null) (target as SomeComponent).scriptable = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance(typeof(MyScriptable)) as MyScriptable;

         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("scriptable"));                                 
         //shows the asset
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("scriptable").FindPropertyRelative("value"));   
         //error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To fix your code you can do this:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

class SomeComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MyScriptable myScriptable;
}

class MyScriptable : ScriptableObject
{
    public float myChildValue = 0.1f;
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(SomeComponent))]
class SomeComponentEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        SomeComponent someComponent = target as SomeComponent;
        if (someComponent.myScriptable == null)
            someComponent.myScriptable = CreateInstance<MyScriptable>();

        SerializedProperty myScriptableProp = serializedObject.FindProperty("myScriptable");
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(myScriptableProp);

        SerializedObject child = new SerializedObject(myScriptableProp.objectReferenceValue);
        SerializedProperty myChildValueProp = child.FindProperty("myChildValue");
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(myChildValueProp);
        child.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

To inspect a child object, you first need to create a *SerializedObject* version of it, which then can be searched for properties as usual.

Also, the *Serializable* attribute is not needed on classes which derive from *ScriptableObject* and the *SerializeField* attribute is only needed when serializing private fields; public fields are serialized by default in Unity.

Without knowing the original context of your code, your approach seems a little peculiar to me. *ScriptableObject* instances are meant to be used as asset files in your Unity project. Have you used the *[CreateAssetMenu](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CreateAssetMenuAttribute.html)* attribute yet? Usually, you would create your assets manually via the menu and then plug them into your components. The way you are doing it, it won't be written to disk, so why use *ScriptableObject* and not just a normal class? But maybe it all makes sense in your actual context, so never mind if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hack solution found:

```
    SerializedObject newserobj = new SerializedObject(serializedObject.FindProperty("scriptable").objectReferenceValue );
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(newserobj.FindProperty("value"));   
    newserobj.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```