# Reference a class from a ScriptableObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an `EnemyData` ScriptableObject that holds data about enemies.  I'd like to have a field on `EnemyData` that references some logic about how this enemy behaves on its turn (in turn-based card game).
My current attempt at this is to structure that as a ScriptableObject too, basically like this:

```cs
public class EnemyData : ScriptableObject
{
    public int health;
    public EnemyAIBase enemyAI;
}

public abstract class EnemyAIBase : ScriptableObject
{
    public abstract void PlayTurn(Enemy thisEnemy);
}

public class PirateShipAI : EnemyAIBase
{
    public override void PlayTurn(Enemy thisEnemy)
    {
        thisEnemy.Heal();
        AttackPlayer();
    }
}
```

So as an example, I've got a "PirateShip" asset of type `EnemyData`, whose enemyAI field points to a "PirateShipAI" asset of type `PirateShipAI`.

But this feels wrong, every time I code up a new enemy's AI I have to also instantiate an asset just so it can be referenced by an `EnemyData`.  I feel like `EnemyAIBase` shouldn't even be an SO, it's not like it has any variables that different assets will override.  There will be a 1-to-1 mapping between `EnemyData` assets and custom AI for that enemy.  So this SO is just a container for some logic, which doesn't feel right.  But I don't know any other way to reference that logic in my `EnemyData` SO.

I guess I wish an SO could reference a C# class directly, but I don't think this is possible.

One option is that I could build an Editor that hides the `EnemyAI` asset as a sub-asset of the `EnemyData` asset, kinda like I did over here: [Building an Editor for nested ScriptableObjects to compose abilities in a card game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62768791/building-an-editor-for-nested-scriptableobjects-to-compose-abilities-in-a-card-g)

But that feels really wrong here, because I don't intend to make any of this AI generic.

How can I attach behavior/logic to a ScriptableObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed simply make it not a `ScriptableObject`. To define different behaviors I would use a [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) here:

```
public abstract class EnemyData<T> : ScriptableObject where T : EnemyAIBase
{
    public int health;
    public T enemyAI;
}

public abstract class EnemyAIBase
{
    public abstract void PlayTurn(Enemy thisEnemy);
}
```

And then from these create your actual implementations

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class PirateShip : EnemyData<PirateShipAI>{ }

public class PirateShipAI : EnemyAIBase
{
    public override void PlayTurn(Enemy thisEnemy)
    {
        thisEnemy.Heal();
        AttackPlayer();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @derHugo, this is interesting!  i'm playing with it, hitting two things that make this feel not very "first class":  (A) references to `EnemyData` become `EnemyData<EnemyAIBase>` which i guess i could alias globally for readability.  (B) i don't think i can serialize a list of generics i.e. a GameObject that holds a list of `EnemyData<EnemyAIBase>` doesn't work: https://forum.unity.com/threads/case-1188478-list-of-generic-type-not-serialized.754442/

Comment: Actually, looks like I can't serialize any of these:     `public EnemyData<EnemyAIBase>[] enemyArray;  public EnemyData<EnemyAIBase> enemy;  public EnemyData<PirateShipAI> pirateShip;`

Comment: Yes that's why you need the explicit implementation `PirateShip` as shown. You could however have a non-genric parent class you can serialize